# How to make activeadmin 0.4.3 work with Rails 3.2.22.2 (Undefined mixin 'box-shadow')?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

I'm trying to update a Rails app 3.1.10 to 3.2.22.2 with the same activeadmin version 0.4.3 if possible.

I have tried to create a fresh Rails 3.2.22.2 install with activeadmin 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.5.0... but the error pop everytime:

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Active_admin/devise/sessions#new
Undefined mixin 'box-shadow'.
(in /Library/WebServer/Documents/boudiou/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css.scss)
```

Here's the full trace: https://gist.github.com/fro/e56f9112c7fcba4a79cb

My Gemfile:

`source 'https://rubygems.org'
    gem 'rails', '3.2.22.2'
    gem 'sqlite3'
    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end
    gem 'jquery-rails'
    gem 'pg'
    gem 'devise'
    gem 'activeadmin', '0.4.3'
    gem 'formtastic', '2.0.2'`

The full gem list:

`actionmailer (3.2.22.2)
actionpack (3.2.22.2)
activeadmin (0.4.3)
activemodel (3.2.22.2)
activerecord (3.2.22.2)
activeresource (3.2.22.2)
activesupport (3.2.22.2)
arbre (1.0.3)
arel (3.0.3)
bcrypt (3.1.11)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
bourbon (4.2.6)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.11.2)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
devise (3.5.6)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.6.0)
fastercsv (1.5.5)
formtastic (2.0.2)
has_scope (0.6.0)
hike (1.2.3)
i18n (0.7.0)
inherited_resources (1.6.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (3.1.4)
json (1.8.3, 1.8.1)
kaminari (0.16.3)
mail (2.5.4)
meta_search (1.1.3)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
multi_json (1.11.2)
orm_adapter (0.5.0)
pg (0.18.4)
polyamorous (0.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.5)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rack (1.4.7)
rack-cache (1.6.1)
rack-ssl (1.3.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (3.2.22.2)
railties (3.2.22.2)
rake (11.1.1, 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0, 3.12.2)
responders (1.1.2)
sass (3.4.21)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.11)
test-unit (3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (1.4.1)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (0.3.47)
uglifier (2.7.2)
warden (1.2.6)`

I've spend 1 full day of testing, looking at stackoverflow solutions... but nothing's working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `bourbon` gem in < `3.1.0`

Comment: Thank you so much... again ;-)